# Camera2 ImageReader freezes repeating capture request

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm trying to capture image data from the camera using the camera2 API. I've mostly used code taken from the android Capture2RAW example. Only a few images come through (i.e. calls to onImageAvailable) before stopping completely. I've tried capturing using the RAW_SENSOR and JPEG formats at different sizes with the same results. What am I doing wrong?

```
this.mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, ImageFormat.RAW_SENSOR, /*maxImages*/ 1);
Surface surface = this.mImageReader.getSurface();
final List<Surface> surfaces = Arrays.asList(surface);
this.mCamera.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
    // Callback methods here
}, null);
CaptureRequest.Builder captureRequestBuilder;
captureRequestBuilder = this.mCamera.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
this.mCaptureRequest = captureRequestBuilder.build();
this.mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequest, null, null);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Fixed it. The Images produced by the ImageReader need to be closed, otherwise they quickly fill up memory.

```
@Override
onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
    Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
    // Process the image
    image.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for explanation! My App was freezing after getting 7 frames.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This API handles memory oddly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have to close your IMAGE, not your READER

Comment: Thanks a million. I spent a whole day, debugging my code thinking there is something wrong with my implementation.