# Camera2 API Working Only for First 5 Pictures

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I have a problem with android camera2. I started from [camera2Basic](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) and changed it so that preview and capture takes manual pictures. So I changed `CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW` and `CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE` both to `CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_MANUAL`.

And I removed the preview callback, because without autofocus there is no need for it. So here is how I take a picture:

```
final CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback captureCallback
                = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                           @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                           @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                showToast("Saved");
                unlockFocus();
            }
        };

mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
mCaptureSession.abortCaptures();
mCaptureSession.capture(mCaptureRequest, captureCallback, null);
```

And in `unlockFocus`:

```
mCaptureSession.capture(mPreviewRequest, null, mBackgroundHandler);
mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequest, mPreviewCaptureCallback,
                mBackgroundHandler);
```

But it works for 5 pictures every time, and then it never goes in `onCaptureCompleted` in the callback and I can't figure out why.

Can someone help me with this ?

*EDIT:*

`captureCallback`'s `onCaptureFailed` says that the image has been taken but the capture failed with `reason == 0` (Error in the framework but I don't know where, and how it could even work for 5 first captures) and the sequence id always go up by two when taking a picture.

So it means that the error occur whenever `seqid > 10`, is there a link ?

Comment: Do you use **ImageReader**? Didn't you forget [to close the image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34666080/192373) ?

Comment: Yea I just solved this, it was so dumb ! Thanks anyway, you answered the moment I came to close my question ^^

Comment: Yeah how could you think of this at first :-) 
I took so much time trying to debug the camera session and capture process without even thinking about that and suddenly I saw that it was after capture and eventually found it but wow it took me a day ^^

Answer (score 1):

So as @Alex Cohn said, I was just forgetting to close the image on the `ImageReader`, and was searching the problem somewhere else.

Here is the corrected `ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener` with no processing of the output image as it was just a test.

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
        = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
        Image image = reader.acquireNextImage();
        image.close();
    }

};
```